# How Do I register an application from an external Azure AD tenant?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have created a Web application in my local Azure AD which I can successfully use to authenticate members of my AD tenant with (using oAuth2 flow). Now I need to extend my supported scenarios to allow a global admin from an external Azure AD tenant to sign-up their company to use this application as well.

Based on the Microsoft Docs this scenario, Multi-Tenant, is supported...

[Authentication Scenarios for Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios)

> Multi-Tenant: If you are building an application that can be used by users outside your organization, it must be registered in your company’s directory, but also must be registered in each organization’s directory that will be using the application. To make your application available in their directory, you can include a sign-up process for your customers that enables them to consent to your application. When they sign up for your application, they will be presented with a dialog that shows the permissions the application requires, and then the option to consent. Depending on the required permissions, an administrator in the other organization may be required to give consent. When the user or administrator consents, the application is registered in their directory. For more information, see Integrating Applications with Azure Active Directory.

From my reading it appears that at some point a global admin for the foreign tenant should be presented with a URL which they can follow ( login.microsoftonline.com/common/??? ) which will somehow cause the external application to precipitate like a morning dew into their Azure AD. However, if this is the correct approach I would appreciate a tokenized example of how one correctly builds the login URL for a multi-tenant external Azure AD application which a group admin can follow to allow access in their AzureAD.

Comment: Any other way register the external user register my application in his azure directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, through trial and failure I have found the solution. The group admin for the remote tenant needs to be provided with the following URL which will allow them to register your Azure AD application as an Enterprise Application in their tenant.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{remoteTenantUrl.com}/adminconsent?client_id={YourAppsClientID}&redirect_uri={YourAppsCallbackPage}
```

Comment: You can also use `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?prompt=admin_consent` and include the rest of the parameters. But I suppose this one is older :)